# Push Notification is not sent using rails-push-notifications in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I referred following site :
https://github.com/calonso/rails-push-notifications

I want to send push notifications to ios device.
So I added following gem into gem file:

```
gem 'rails-push-notifications', '~> 0.2.0'
```

Then executed "bundle install".
Created new controller "ApnsController". And added following code:

```
  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token
  def push_notifications_demo#create
      app = RailsPushNotifications::APNSApp.new
      app.apns_dev_cert = File.read("#            {Rails.root}/public/Ventureout_Push_Development.p12")
      app.apns_prod_cert = File.read("#{Rails.root}/public/Ventureout_Push_Development.p12")
      app.sandbox_mode = true
      app.save

     notification = app.notifications.create(
                   destinations: [
   '917297e41cbce67a8b21e27c89027e9a81524992537abff4d168da6f1d76f528',
    # '9b4ee9606b698c3134e536d90c833a7cdda19d0cb72f661f96f4b2504ba49366',
    # '74246086ea26cad8f112ac778e45140a19a0fd824084e436bf8b1b078fd90ec7'
                   ],
   data: { aps: { alert: 'Hello APNS World!', sound: 'true', badge: 1 } ,"sent":"with apns gem"}
   )

   app.push_notifications
   render json:{
                                 success:true,
                                 message:"Push notification sent."
         }, status: 200

 end
```

Records are created and getting saved in `rails_push_notifications_apns_apps` and `rails_push_notifications_notifications` . But for notification record it is `saving =>`

```
success: 0

failed: 1
```

In terminal I can see:

```
SQL (0.9ms)  UPDATE `rails_push_notifications_notifications` SET `results` = '--- !ruby/object:RubyPus
hNotifications::APNS::APNSResults\nindividual_results:\n-  255\nsuccess: 0\nfailed: 1\n', `sent` = 1, `su
ccess` = 0, `failed` = 1, `updated_at` = '2015-08-12 07:30:29.306500'    WHERE `rails_push_notifications_no
tifications`.`id` = 11
(31.6ms)  COMMIT
```